# ViewBag in static method of controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to mvc and I load ViewBag in a method of controller as,

```
HomeController: Controller
{
    Public ActionResult Index()
    {
        loadViewBag();
        return View();
    }

    public void loadViewBag()
    {
      ViewBag.aaa = "something";
    }
}
```

It works fine.

What is my problem is, Now I want to call loadViewBag() method form another controller( say Account) so that I can reuse same method and need to make loadViewBag() method static due to some static variables as:
`public static void loadViewBag()`
If I make loadViewBag method static, there appear error on ViewBag " *An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.ViewBag.get'* ".

Is there any solution/suggestion.

Thank You.

Answer (score 10):

Just make it an extension method of ControllerBase e.g.

```
public static void ControllerExt
{
    public static void LoadViewBag(this ControllerBase controller)
    {
        controller.ViewBag.aaa = "something";
        ...
    }
}
```

That way you can use it in *any* controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        this.LoadViewBag();
        return View();
    }
}

public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        this.LoadViewBag();
        return View();
    }
}
```

If its only specific to *some* controllers then it would be more flexible to pass the ViewBag property in e.g.

```
public static class ControllerHelper
{
    public static void LoadViewBag(dynamic viewBag)
    {
         viewBag.aaa = "something";
    }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ControllerHelper.LoadViewBag(ViewBag);
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`ViewBag` is a property of your controller (more specifically of `ControllerBase`), and since a static method has no knowledge of a class instance, you can't access it.

You *could* pass the controller instance to the method if you want to use a static method or even make it an extension method, but depending on your problem, this solution could be sub-optimal. You may be able to get a better answer if you add more details to your question.

```
Public ActionResult Index()
{
    this.loadViewBag();
    return View();
}

public static void loadViewBag(this ControllerBase target)
{
    target.ViewBag.aaa = "something";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you need that to allow different controllers/views to use some common properties?

Then I'd rather recommend a common base controller, while also wrapping `ViewBag` code into type safe properties (to let the compiler control the data consistency - as you know, `ViewBag` is not type safe, so any typos and data mismatches won't be noticed until the code gets executed).

### 1. Introduce a common controller with those wrapper properties

```
public abstract class MyBaseController : Controller
{
    internal long CurrentUserId
    {
        get { return ViewBag.CurrentUserId; }
        set { ViewBag.CurrentUserId = value; }
    }

    internal Role CurrentUserRole
    {
        get { return ViewBag.CurrentUserRole; }
        set { ViewBag.CurrentUserRole = value; }
    }

    ...
}
```

Thus, your inherited controllers could simply set the properties - or, with lots of common code just introduce a method in your base controller - similar to what you already have.

### 2. Introduce a common view class with those wrapper properties

```
public abstract class MyBaseViewPage<T> : WebViewPage<T>
{
    public string Title
    {
        get { return (string)ViewBag.Title; }
        set { ViewBag.Title = value; }
    }

    public long CurrentUserId
    {
        get { return (long)ViewBag.CurrentUserId; }
    }

    public Role CurrentUserRole
    {
        get { return ViewBag.CurrentUserRole; }
    }
}

public abstract class MyBaseViewPage : MyBaseViewPage<dynamic>
{
}
```

and update `web.config` to let MVC know you're using a custom base view:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    ...
    <pages pageBaseType="MyRootNamespace.Views.MyBaseViewPage">
      ...
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Now you can use them as normal properties in your controllers and views.